# Beta smartphone/PDA with Adobe Flash, circa 2000

Tags: pda

I'm trying to find reference to an early smartphone concept, in fact I think it may have seen beta release around 2000. It was trying to preempt what a smartphone would eventually become, like a more web-centric PDA. It boasted that it could run Macromedia Flash (subsequently Adobe Flash, now discontinued) as native apps. It had a stylus and was a sort of pinched rectangle shape with blue corners that contained the aerial, stylus and sockets.

I was a Flash developer back then, so was quite interested in this thing, but I only just remembered it and persistent googling turned up nothing. Does anybody remember it?

EDIT: I don't think it was from a well-known manufacturer, I feel like the whole project was a failed start-up. This was sort of the shape of the thing, to the best of my recollection:

[image: approximate shape of device]

Comment: IMHO it's a perfect fitting question. A fewmore hints, liek what hardware or manufacturer oe basicstylemight be helpful.

Comment: Would it be potentially a Pocket PC? From some googling I see that some of them in the early 2000s had flash players (https://www.hpcfactor.com/forums/forums/thread-view.asp?tid=4930&start=1). The Pocket PC brand was introduced in 2000.

Comment: Some Sony Cliés (running Palm OS) also had Macromedia Flash Player in ROM, *e.g.* [the TH55](https://web.archive.org/web/20161226085632/http://www.mobiletechreview.com/feature/sony_TH55.htm), released in 2004.

Comment: Wow! Thanks everyone for your replies, they've helped me to refine the question a little.

Comment: There's a Flash Handhelds section at https://web.archive.org/web/20041207201129/http://www.macromedia.com/cfusion/webforums/forum/index.cfm?forumid=15 but all I see are PocketPC comments.